# Can I share my internet connection and redirect clients to my web server?

Tags: internet-sharing, webserver

I often share my internet connection with other Macs and devices and want to know if I can redirect client's web requests to my local web server.

Is it as simple as having them use my client's IP address or do I need to set up a proxy or otherwise configure things on my Mac or my client's devices?

Comment: I don't think so, redirection is quite complicated.

Comment: I agree, the internet sharing feature is really limited to simple sharing, with virtually no advanced configurable options.

Comment: What about a proxy server? there must be a way!?

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to configure your network in such a way,
here are a few bricks I'd advise to start with:

1. Install [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) version 3 and configure it in transparent
   mode. You may use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to build, configure and install it.
   With `MacPorts` you would do it with: `port install squid3`.
2. Install [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/). With the same `Macports`, you would have to
   do it with: `port install apache2`.

You will find many documents on the web to help to build this, but I didn't find any one complete and good enough to recommand it.